# Thread.sleep() alternatives

Tags: java, multithreading, sleep

I want this boolean to change from false to true after 5 seconds(This is the code I have currently)

```
checkUser = false;
    loginMessage2 = "Error connecting to server.";
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    checkUser = true;
```

But I don't want the entire client to freeze, I am not using multi threading or anything of the sort

Comment: *"But I don't want the entire thread to stop..."* What do you want it to do in the meantime?

Comment: So call other Thread if you want this Thread to continue to run

Comment: Like @T.J.Crowder said, what's the need ? :)

Comment: Sorry I had worded it wrong @T.J.Crowder

Edited 

Thread.sleep() freezes the entire client, I just want a short pause between boolean changes, does that make sense?

Comment: @MaximShoustin Maybe a timer can come in handy ?

Comment: Timer is better, sure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to consider looking into a `Timer` that executes 5 seconds after you ask it to execute. Execute the timer only once.

That way, you get what you want and at the same time you do not freeze the application. The timer itself is a different thread so it will not block your application.

Swing timer tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html

A very very short example:

```
ActionListener listener = new ActionListener(){
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
    checkUser = true;
  }
};
Timer checkUserTimer = new Timer(5000, listener); // the 5 second gap
checkUserTimer.start(); // start the timer.
```